# iteratively create lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a way to iteratively create a lambda expression
representing for instance a sum of many functions

```
interface lambda{
   double apply(double x);
}
lambda func = x -> 0;

for(i=0; i < 100; i++){
   func = x -> func.apply(x) + i*x;
}
```

seems not to work?

Comment: Sum would suffice. Making it iteratively 'final' worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
...

lambda func = x -> 0;

for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
    final int index = i;
    final lambda finalFunc = func;
    func = x -> finalFunc.apply(x) + index*x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, eclipse does not complain!